# How to write articles about software applications. Where to find free examples?

Tags: documentation

A lot of you have starting to write programs since college or even earlier. 
When you were on university the level of professionalism increased.

If you have to write an article about your software application how do you do it? I'm not talking about a documentation or help manual. I'm talking about an article/paper for academia world.  Do you have any idea where can I find those type of articles for free?

This is also a programmer job, even we like to do it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually papers are rarely about software itself but rather about concepts, ideas and algorithms. Those are *explored* through software and the authors may give specific examples how they implemented those in their software but most papers are not specifically about a software application itself as those usually have very little valuable content.

There are only few of such papers I've come across so far:

- [SPRNG: a scalable library for pseudorandom number generation.](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=358407.358427&coll=Portal&dl=ACM&CFID=53086435&CFTOKEN=93109039)
- [Presto: An Experimental Architecture for Fluid Interactive Document Spaces.](http://www2.parc.com/csl/projects/placeless/papers/tochi-presto.pdf)

Other papers may follow which then concentrate on how specific optimizations or changes were implemented and also new ideas. But I think in those areas real innovation is rare and there is much more text than actual content.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www2.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/abs/proceedings/ecbs/1996/7355/00/73550198abs.htm)'s one I made (much) earlier.

> Abstract:
>
> This paper presents details of the
> Safety Argument Manager (SAM) a PC
> based tool to support safety case
> construction. SAM is novel in that it
> stresses total system safety and is
> designed to support an integrated
> process for design and assessment. SAM
> provides facilities for the
> construction of high level safety
> arguments and for building up complete
> and consistent supporting evidence. In
> this paper we focus on the achievement
> of high quality supporting evidence,
> by describing SAM's facilities for
> integrated modeling and safety
> assessment. We also illustrate the use
> of SAM with a car braking system
> example.

What it does, why it's novel, how it does it at a high level, small concrete example shown end-to-end.

Comment: oke. thx for the answer, but this doesn't seems to be free at all:(

Comment: Many large companies have site-wide subscriptions to 'Xplore', so ask at work. It's also well worth getting ACM digital library membership if you don't mind paying something, and it gives quite a wide scope. Sometimes you can get copies off the contributors' home pages, but this is too old so it's gone from cs.york.ac.uk.

Answer (score 1):

Google Scholar is exceptionally useful for finding freely available academic publications, particularly in the CS/software world.

While many peer-reviewed journals hide things behind paywalls, academics have a tendency to publish working versions or drafts on their personal websites and such.  You can find these using Google Scholar (by clicking the "See all X versions" link).